# How to RunDll32 a file without installing it using WiX?

Tags: wix

I'm trying to call RunDll32 on a DLL to install a private key to the machines key store at install time but I don't want to put the file down on disk.  I currently have a custom action calls the RunDll and then deletes the file (after it has been installed obviously).

Is there a way to do it without first installing the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the Certificate element instead?

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out how to use the Certificate element, and found this. This answer would be better with an example. Is this one up to date enough? http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2009/02/11/installing-certificates-using-wix-windows-installer-xml-voltive/

Comment: @RobMensching: bah, Rob, I know you are the "god" of WiX, but this kind of response is not helping anybody...

Comment: @woohoo, why doesn't that help? I find many people don't necessarily know about all of the extended functionality of the WiX toolset. I'm sure there isn't a tutorial that says, "When installing private key on the machine use the Certificate element." So I thought I'd point out that this would do it. Then Epu found a link to a blog entry that does a nice job talking about the Certificate element in more detail.